# Using char array properly in vc++

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, gdi+

I am trying to convert an IStream to HBITMAP using the GDI+ Bitmap class. The IStream object is being populated by using data from a web service. I am reading the data in parts and appending it to an object to be used later with the Bitmap class.

Here is the relevant part of the code

```
        char data1[] = "";
        int offset = 0;

        LPTSTR pszString = NULL;
        LPSTREAM lpStream = NULL;

        CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, TRUE, &lpStream);
        StreamStringCopy ((LPSTREAM)lpStream, (LPCTSTR)"");
        while(of->pread(&data1,1023,offset) > 0){
            LPCTSTR tempStr = data1;
            StreamStringCat ((LPSTREAM)lpStream, tempStr);
            offset = offset + strlen(data1);    
        }
        Bitmap bm(lpStream,FALSE);
        bm.GetHBITMAP(Color.Black, &ret);
```

StreamStringCat appends the string to the LPSTREAM object so I can get a single LPSTREAM object.

The loop runs fine only the first time. When the while loop is entered again, the &data1 gives an Access violation exception.

Can someone please tell me how I should resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be careful with string literals. String literals like `""` are of type `const char*`, so you cannot write to them. I'm not entirely sure whether your construct `char data1[] = ""` makes it writable, but even if so, you have only memory for 2 characters there, while you (I suppose) try to read 1023 bytes into the location of `data1`. Try this:

```
char* data1 = static_cast<char*> (std::malloc (1024 * sizeof (char));

...

std::free (data1);

// or try this
char data1 [1024] = { 0 }; // Gives you 1024 bytes to write to on the stack
```

This allocates some memory, which can be written to. I guess after the first run, you've overwritten some memory, which leads to the access violation in the next run.